# HTML5 Video // Hiding controls on full screen if mouse is not moved

Tags: html, video, cursor, hide, fullscreen

I am trying to make my Video controls hide when I am in full screen and not moving my mouse. Then when I move my mouse the controls will pop up again.
I am using the framework VideoJs. 
How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you [onmousemove event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp). If the video is fullscreen and the mouse is not moving, hide the controls.

Example:
//windowifisfullscreen ->its just a example, not a real.

```
    if(windowifisfullscreen)
    {
    document.onmousemove = function(){
    document.getElementById("contros").style.display="block";
    }
else{
 document.getElementById("contros").style.display="none";
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I understand how to do it now.